# Airflow from BaseOperator to PythonOperator or passing arguments to BaseOperator

Tags: python-3.x, architecture, airflow

I have DAG in AirFlow, which contain two tasks:

- Sensor (it is scanning DB every 10 sec and search new keys) and
- BuldingTask (receive from Sensor over XCom new scan data and create new data row).

`BuldingTask` inherits from class `BuildingChannel1`, which inherits from `AbstractChannelBuilder(BaseOperator)`.

This structure works but I have to rebuild it.

We have API, which writing data about creating channel in another DB.

From this API I want to send request (with info about new data) to trigger dag (AirFlow allows it because expiremental api).

How can I pass arguments (conf key in URL) to `BuldingTask` with new info? `PythonOperator` can receive this arguments, but `python_callable` will be huge.

Comment: May I use PythonOperator to run function within run  BuldingTask?

Comment: Don't work. Error Argument ['task_id'] is required

Comment: If you passing arguments to dag in conf. Access to this JSON container: context['dag_run'].conf